# Why array element is not displayed in ng-repeat structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I used $scope but my array is not displayed. I came from knockoutjs and this is really strange.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yiping/4hu9eaoj/

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('T', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Test = "AAA";
    $scope.todos = [{
        text: 'learn angular',
        done: true
    }, {
        text: 'build an angular app',
        done: false
    }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="T">{{Test}}
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li ng-repeat="todo in T.todos"> <span>{{todo.text}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to explicitly refer to the controller in the `ng-repeat` call -- `ng-repeat="todo in todos"` is fine.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b1dotx4y/1/

Comment: Thanks but on AngularJS homepage they use "<li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos">"

Comment: In that case, `todoList` is a data object, not the controller name.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ng-repeat="todo in T.todos"` to `ng-repeat="todo in todos"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `T.todos` and use just `todos` in the view. Otherwise use controller as notation like `T as t in ng-controller`. Then use `t.todos`.